# pytorch: NLLLoss ignore_index default value

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

in the pytorch NLLLoss [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.NLLLoss.html) the default of ignore_index is -100 instead of the usual `None`, are there any particular reasons? seems like any negative value is equivalent.

BTW, what may be the reason that I would want to ignore an index? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value for `ignore_index` must be an *int*, that's why the default value is an *int* and not `None`. The default value is arbitrary, it could have been any negative number, *i.e.* anything that is not a "valid" class label. The function will ignore all elements for which the target instance has that class label. In practice, this option can be used to identify unlabeled pixels for example in dense prediction tasks.

---

*Edit*: Tracing back the implementation of [`nn.NLLLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.NLLLoss.html), we can find this comment in the `nll_loss` implementation of [`torch/onnx/symbolic_opset12.py`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/aa5d2a8d867991fc8541e197112c35a8eba18182/torch/onnx/symbolic_opset12.py#L41):

```
# in onnx NegativeLogLikelihoodLoss specification, ignore_index is optional without default value.
# therefore we need to set ignore_index attribute even if it is not specified (e.g. ignore_index=-100).
ignore_index = sym_help._maybe_get_const(ignore_index, "i")
```

Comment: Another common example is padding within batches of differently sized tensors; this is a very common occurrence for textual inputs (e.g., very few text snippets have *exactly* the same length).

Answer (score 1):

I feel that they should have used `None` as a default. Python is not statically typed, so there is no need for `ignore_index` to be an *int* (And even statically typed languages like C++ have option types these days) Failing that, they could have used `-1`, which is less jarring.

So why didn't they use `-1`, at least?

One possibility is that the authors were afraid that `-1` would be misinterpreted as "the last one". I was able to find that the `-100` was inherited from the Lua version of Torch. Although in Lua, `-1` doesn't generally mean "last", Lua Torch's `Tensor` class [used this convention](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md).